# rails model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am really new to rails and I am trying to create a products ratings model.

So there's users (name, email, pw)

Users has a list of products that the user has rated. With a rating (1-10) and a comment.

Each product has its description, a list of the users who rated them, the rating and the comment.

How should I create the relationship? Should I have 3 models, user, rating, product, or can I get by with just user and product?

Also what would be the :has_many .etc relationship look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would a great case for a `has_many :through =>`

**User Model.**

```
User has_many :ratings
User has_many :products, :though => :ratings
```

**Rating Model.**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

**Product Model.**

```
Product has_many :ratings
Product has_many :users, :through => ratings
```

n.b. this is now considered superior to `has_and_belongs_to_many` which many folks consider to be basically deprecated at this point.
Personally I've never liked using `has_many_and_belongs_to`, both as it works and also because of the frequent re-work to turn it into has_many, :through as soon as an additional attribute is desired on the join model (ratings in this case).
Actually you want a rating 'level' so you already have a case for the `has_many, :through` !

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do

```
class User
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :products, :through => :ratings
end

class Product
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :users, :through => :ratings
end

class Rating
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This way if you wanted to get all the users that have rated a product, you can say `product.users`.